# How to create an app with User Profiles like Facebook, Instagram, etc

Tags: ios

Hi there I was wondering how it would be possible to make a app like Facebook, or Instagram or other Social Network apps where users can login view their profiles and other peoples profiles. I was wondering if anybody would know what programming language I have to know or if I have to have servers. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the site!

This question is asking for a lot and not really really appropriate for this site, but how about some good starting points?

1. Building apps like facebook, instragram, etc are very difficult. Fortunately there are many great tools to help with this, like Ruby on Rails, Play, Django, etc.
2. There are many programing languages you can use to build an app like this. PHP, Ruby, Python, Java, Clojure, etc. You can even make a website in pure assembly if you want to.
3. Servers and database knowledge are required to get started as well.

Fear not, for we all have to start somewhere.

Here's some steps I recommend you take:

1. Learn how to make a website with HTML and CSS.
2. Learn some javascript, and understand how programming is dynamic.
3. Try languages like Ruby or Python, and learn about the power they bring.
4. Learn a web framework in the language you preferred with from suggestion 3. Rails and Django are two major frameworks used today, both have clear getting started tutorials.
5. Try grabbing an account at Codecademy or CodeSchool. They both have amazing step-by-step guides to help you get started with the right knowledge.
6. Build your app with profiles, etc.
7. Build a mobile app around your web-service if you'd like.

In summary, it's all about patience, determination, taking on new levels of complexity at the right time and of course, the amazing feeling when all your hard work pays off and your app works!

Good luck!